# Deleting remote changes after git pull

Tags: git

I was working on some code that, in hurry, I screwed up because of which i had to git -reset to a previous commit. Now that I've got it working fine, doing git push says that my current branch is behind the remote branch. I'm afraid that by doing git pull and merging the changes with the remote branch my code will again go back to the buggy version. Is there a way where I complete reject the changes of remote branch and instead keep the new one only? (and i can go back to pushing changes to the remote repo)

Thanks a lot

Comment: you can force push, but I recommend saving work on the remote in a separate branch... git push origin -f master

Comment: Take a look at [`git push --force`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-push.html). Be very careful with it though.

Answer (score 3):

*If*

- No one else depends upon the code you publish; rewriting history is mean, and
- Your local branch is exactly what you want the remote branch to be, and
- No one else has pushed any changes in the meantime.

`git push -f origin <branch>`

Answer (score 2):

You could do a `git push --force origin branchname`, but that is probably not the best solution if you branch has been shared.

Next time, instead of just doing a `git reset --hard` and changing your history, you should revert the specific commits you care about - or you should apply a commit that undoes what you wanted to do.

Fortunately, git is insane and lets you fix this even with what you've currently got.

To do this looks something like this (starting from the branch you care about pushing eventually - lets call it `master`):

```
git branch good_tree          # save a branch with your recent commits
git reset --hard last_good    # reset working tree to fix pushed problem
git fetch --all               # update local repo with remote changes
git reset origin/master       # move pointer to where remote repo's master is
                              # without changing working tree from last_good
git add; git commit; git push # commit fixed stuff
git checkout good_tree        # rebase your changes from last_good
git rebase master             # tack good_tree onto master from undone changes
git checkout master           # go back to master
git merge good_tree           # now you are back to where you want to be
git push                      # and you can push
```

... ish -- you may have conflicts.